# Open a new activity after clicking the Button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

Hello I'm new in programming code, and I'm creating an android app. I'm trying to create an intent for opening a new activity after hitting a button.

Here is my xml of the main activity, just the button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/logIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="openLogIn"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

and here is my mainActivity Java:

```
package com.example.android;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.android.linexpress.DisplayLogInActivity;
import com.example.android.linexpress.R;

/**
 * Created by EnriqueAlcacer on 15/06/2017.
 */

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void opeLogIn (View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayLogInActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: your code seems ok except `openLogIn` . you've wrote wrong name `opeLogIn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you are new in android programming, I would not encourage you in using of onClick from XML.

You should get a reference for the button with findViewById function, then you should set a listener on it.

It will look like

```
Button btnLogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logIn);
btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Mainactivity.this, DisplayLogInActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 
});
```

If you are not passing intent data, you can use the shortened form:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayLogInActivity.class););
```

Comment: this is not an answer of his question

Comment: Sorry, I can not comment because I don't ave enough reputations :(
I just want to help witha  little advice.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
 android:onClick="openLogIn"
```

should match with your function name in activity ..so change it to :

```
public void openLogIn (View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DisplayLogInActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Make sure you add `DisplayLogInActivity` in manifest also

Comment: Thank you for your help, I fixed

Answer (score 1):

In setOnclicklistener add intent to next activity and put the data you want to pass in putextra function.

Comment: Thank you for your help I fixed

Answer (score 0):

You Just have a Typo mistake.
Make both the Java and XML onClick method the same name `openLogIn`

Comment: Thank you very much I fixed

Answer (score 0):

This approach has such Limitation: `android:onClick` is for API level >=4

Answer (score 0):

implement View.OnClickListener

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id=view.getId();
        switch(id){
           case: R.id.logIn
              Intent i = new Intent(MainAvtivity.this,DisplayLogInActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

Inside OnCreate set a listener like

```
Button logIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.LogIn);
logIn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Thats it.